# How to group the data by date in Php or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, t-sql

I have a table in mysql

```
comment_id   comment_by_user   comment_date                comment_body
  1244         david_sam       2013-02-27 15:46:53          xyz
  1245         raymond_davis   2013-02-27 13:46:53          xyz
  1246         jam_jam         2013-02-14 18:46:53          xyz
```

I want to show this data as

```
2013-02-27 -------------------------------------
1244       david_sam        15:46      xyz     
1245       raymond_davis    13:46      xyz
2013-02-14 -------------------------------------
1246       jam_jam          18:46      xyz
```

How can I do that, Which SQL Query and Which PHP Method?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: To make life easier for yourself your SQL query should only return the date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd. If you return the time too you will just need to filter it out at a later stage.

Comment: MySQL cannot produce the output you are asking for. Instead, you would select `DATE(comment_date) as comment_date` along with your other columns. In your PHP output, you must test in each loop iteration if the date has changed, and if it has, output a new header.

Answer (score 2):

You can just select all the needed columns

```
select comment_id, comment_by_user,
       date(comment_date), time(comment_date), comment_body
from comments
order by comment_date desc, comment_id
```

and then output the rows and insert an additional line when the date changes

```
$current_date = '';
while (list($id, $user, $date, $time, $body) = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    if ($date != $current_date) {
        echo "$date ----\n";
        $current_date = $date;
    }

    echo "$id $user $time $body\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `comment_date` DESC
```

And your php code should br like this..

```
$date = '';
foreach($records as $record)
{
    if($date != date('Y-m-d'), strtotime($record->comment_date))
    {
        //  print "2013-02-14 -------------------------------------";
        $date = date('Y-m-d'), strtotime($record->comment_date);
    }

    //  print "1246       jam_jam          18:46      xyz";
}
```